# How to call jQuery popup function in registered script in c#?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, popup

I registered script block with jQuery popup open on clicking of class element. Script completely registered but popup can't open while clicking of class element.

Below code is registered script in c# and i want to call popup on clicking of `my_modal_open` class

```
public void RegisterScript()
        {
            string script = @"function DownloadFiles() {alert('fds');
                $('#my_modal').width('auto');
                $('#my_modal').popup({
                    'autoopen': true,
                    'reposition': true,
                    'autozindex': true
                });
                return false;
            }
$(document).ready(function () {
                $('.my_modal_open').click(function () {
                    $('#my_modal').popup({
                        'autoopen': true,
                        'reposition': false,
                        'autozindex': true
                    });
                }); 
               });
            ";
            //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "RegisterClientScriptBlock", script, true);
            this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page.GetType(), "RegisterClientScriptBlock", script, true);
        }
```

Below is HTML format of open popup in iframe

```
<div id="my_modal" class="well" style="display: none; width: auto; z-index: 1000;">
    <a href="#" class="my_modal_close" style="float: right; padding: 0 0.4em;">×</a>
    <iframe name="frDownloadFiles" runat="server" id="frDownloadFiles" src="about:blank"
        frameborder="0" width="auto" scrolling="no" style="min-height: 300px;"></iframe>
</div>
```

Below code is calling function and set popup window format.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (!Page.IsPostBack)
                {
                    BindControl();
frDownloadFiles.Attributes.Add("src", "../DownloadDataPackFiles.aspx?DataPackageID=" + CurrentDataPackages.Id.ToString());
                    RegisterScript();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "RegisterClientScriptBlock", script, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `RegisterStartupScript` to call javascript on pageload

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
          if (!Page.IsPostBack)
          {
             BindControl();
             frDownloadFiles.Attributes.Add("src", "../DownloadDataPackFiles.aspx?DataPackageID=" + CurrentDataPackages.Id.ToString());
             ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
             cs.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"RegisterScript" ,"RegisterScript();");

         }
}
```

Use **[RegisterStartupScript on Pageload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**

**Note:** Don't forget to give the simicolon `RegisterScript();`

Comment: its not working... that print "RegisterScript();" text on Page.

Comment: ya its working, when using 'ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "RegisterClientScriptBlock", script, true);' this part

Comment: great ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript also works